# Help building a sql query that uses inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to build a sql query that I think it involves inner joins, but I can't figure it out. Here's the model:

There's two tables: comments, posts

Among many columns, there's the following important ones: `comments.id`, `comments.user_id` (owner), `comments.post_id` (reference to posts table), `posts.id`, `posts.editor_id` (which is the person, ie, owner of post).

I want to get the comments that either

1) current user has written, so something like:

```
select * from comments where user_id = <<current_user_id>>
```

2) (Assume `current_user` is editor). Get all comments that belong to a post that you have created.
This is what I have, but I get multiple lines....what am I missing?

```
select * FROM comments INNER JOIN posts ON comments.post_id = <<test_id>>
WHERE posts.editor_id = <<current_user.editor_id>>;
```

If you could give me a sql query that includes both of these things, that would be amazing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure what you mean by "multiple lines" as you would return a row for each comment. 
This should do it.

```
SELECT comments.* 
FROM comments 
INNER JOIN posts 
ON comments.post_id = posts.id   
WHERE posts.editor_id = @editorID;
```

Comment: But this will not satisfy the first requirement, "I want to get the comments that either 1) current user has written".

Comment: My understanding was that the op  had satisfied the first example and was getting issues with the second.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the comments that either 1) current user has written, so something like: select * from comments where user_id = <>

That's correct. What's wrong with that?

> Get all comments that belong to a post that you have created. This is what I have, but I get multiple lines

Well... you're supposed to. Looking at the schema it's indeed a post could contain many comments. The query given by tyrongower should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Going with your requirements, this should work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM comments 
WHERE (user_id = 1) 
OR (post_id IN (SELECT id FROM post WHERE editor_id = 1))
```

In the above query "1" is used as a sample and should be replace with the id of current user.

Comment: That wuld throw an exception if said editor had more than one post, your subquery would need to be preceded with "in" not "="

Comment: Sorry missed that. Just edited it and replace with IN. Thanks.